# Exporting node-printer in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I was able to get node-printer to work on my local machine for my electron app to print this certain pdf I have. The issue is that when I build and package the app and install it on a different machine, it doesn't work. Do these other machines also need to have those dependencies of python and VS2013 that I needed to install the module? If so what would be the alternative be since I don't want my users to have install python, VS2013, and node gyp just to make printing work?

Comment: did you tried to use the printer directive of electron ?

Comment: @ Paulo Galdo Sandoval I used electron's printer but it doesn't give back any errors if there are no default printers installed (or no printers installed at all)

Comment: ohh well, that's a problem, but you can pop the printers menu to select one an send the print.